How to redirect requests to remote machine to localhost using nftables?
I have the following nftables configuration:
[root@localhost andrew]# nft list ruleset
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        ip daddr 10.0.2.99 dnat to 127.0.0.1
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
    }
}

and
[root@localhost andrew]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
[root@localhost andrew]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet
1

but when I try to make a TCP connection (from the same machine) to 10.0.2.99:4000, with a server listening on 0.0.0.0:4000 nothing happens (I can include the server and client, but they're just basic Python scripts written to test this; there is no machine at 10.0.2.99).
Why doesn't this work?  The error I get from Python is "OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host"
If it helps any
[root@localhost andrew]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:39:a4:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 83297sec preferred_lft 83297sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe39:a4e5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

and I am running on Rocky 9.3 (a VM inside VirtualBox).  The nf_tables module is present.
PS I want this to work for all ports.

Are you trying to redirect requests made from this same VM or requests made by some other machine?

from this same vm.

someone made a comment which, amongst other things, said that 127.0.0.1 is not valid here.  then they deleted it when i asked for more info - not sure if they were wrong, or embarrassed by the (rather unfriendly) tone they used.

That was me, and I deleted that comment because 127.0.0.1 staying within the same host is valid so is not an issue anymore. I was focusing on the case of using an separate system as client. I might have become a bit condescending in the 2nd comment because I was focusing on the case where there is a separate system as client, and that case doesn't exist. But anyway you should update your question to explain everything is done on the same system.
